# I want to buy Tencent stock - whats the difference between 0700, TCEHY and NNND?

Tags: stocks, broker, china

I'm a little lost here...

I'm from the UK and my broker is only showing Tencent Holdings Ltd (DE).

Why does Tencent Holding Ltd have so many ticker symbols:
0700, TCEHY and NNND?

Answer (score 2):

Tencent, like many other companies, is listed on multiple exchanges. 0700 is the ticker on the Hong Kong Stock Exchange, NNND is the ticker on the Frankfurt Stock Exchange, whereas TCEHY is the OTC (over-the-counter) symbol.

Comment: What things must be considered when deciding which exchange to purchase on?
For example I know there will be foreign exchange effects when purchasing on a foreign one, but for example some listed on the US are ADR which means you don't actually own the stock (eg TCEHY)

Comment: Timezone, local currency, trade volume/liquidity, transaction costs... come to mind